# Even-spaced (two) columns in reference page using bibtex - automatically

Tags: bibtex, vertical-alignment, two-column

I have a document I keep compiling, using latex and bibtex, and it automatically creates my reference page. My final page is references and I use two columns, so naturally, assuming the reference page is not full, I get a full left column and a less-than-full right column.

I need the reference page to be evenly spaced between the columns. I usually do the following: After compiling, I edit the .bbl file and insert `\vfill\pagebreak` after the 'middle' reference. The problem is that after each compilation I need to re-do this.

I'm sorry not to have an MWE but it would require uploading a complete library of references...

Appreciate any comments.
Thanks,
Ido.

Comment: Thanks, but I use IEEEtran bibliography style, so I would like it to be of minimal change, certainly not changing a complete file...

Comment: Okay, I found the solution: 
``\usepackage{balance}`` 
and then before the bibliography - ``\balance`` . 
Thanks!